# angularJs : length of array.push equals 0

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to use the result of the push() function , but i get that the length of the result table is 0, here is my code :

```
 Task.getTaskbyId(result.data.ftListe[i].tacheid).then(function(result)
                   {               
                      task.push(result.data.tachelistes);

                   }); 

              }
              console.log(task.length); // here i get 0 
              for(var j=0;j<task.length;j++)
              {
                //code 
              }
```

why does the length equals 0 ? 
Ps : when I use the task table in the view i get the objects inside it so it's not empty.

Is there something i'm missing ?

Comment: Where is `var task` setted/initialized? Is `task` an array?

Comment: @Mistalis Yes it is an array and it's initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `Task.getTaskbyId` is asynchronous , if you push item to array in its callback, then you have move the `for-loop` into the `callback`.

**Note**

If you put a breakpoint at the row of `push` and `console.log`, you will see the `console.log` run first.

```
Task.getTaskbyId(result.data.ftListe[i].tacheid).then(function(result)
{               
    task.push(result.data.tachelistes);
    console.log(task.length); // here i get 0 
    for(var j=0;j<task.length;j++)
    {
        //code 
    }
});
```

Comment: you're right I didn't pay attention to this detail, thank you it worked now :)

Comment: is there a way to use the for loop outside the callback ?

Comment: @jihane as I answered, if you put for-loop outside callback, the for-loop will always run first.

Comment: yeah that's the problem, but when i put the foor loop inside the callback and since i have another for-loop already runing before the current for loop, it all starts over and i get repetitive values.

Comment: @jihane yeah, looking though your code, I can guess you are looping through a outside async call's result. maybe you should consider solving this problem from serverside.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to achieve is more something like this I suppose:

```
var tasks = [];    
Task.getTaskbyId(result.data.ftListe[i].tacheid).then(function(result)
                       {
                          result.data.tachelistes.forEach(function(t) {
                              tasks.push(t);
                          });
                       }); 
                  }
                  console.log(tasks.length); // here i get 0 
                  tasks.forEach(function(task) {
                             //
                  });
```